# Load function from one view controller from another view controller

Tags: swift

I have a view controller called FacilityViewController with a function called getToken. I would like to call this function from another view controller called ViewController. So far I have tried to create an observer on FacilityViewController like this:

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(FacilityViewController.getToken(Login:false)), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "getToken"), object: nil)
```

but I am getting error that says:

> instance member getToken can not be used on type FacilityViewController

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `false` from your `#selector` statement. You cannot pass values for the arguments to methods being described in a selector.